What will happen if the Impedance of wireless power power transfer TX coil and RX coil are different
I am new to WPT. Currently I am characterizing the coils to be used used for our WPT.I measured the inductance of TX coil and RX coil at 100Khz.
The impedance of RX coil is 4.5uH @ 100Khz and that of TX coil is 10.6 @ 100Khz.
May I know does these cause any issues.
What are the characteristics of a good coil used in WPT
When can we say the selected coils are good and can be used for WPT

Your last two questions were answered here

The inductance of the transmit coil and the load requirements of the transmitter should correspond to one another, and, the inductance of the receive coil and the input requirements of the receiver should correspond to one another. There is no requirement that the inductance of the transmit coil match the inductance of the receive coil. They can be different.
The two coils together form a loosely coupled transformer, and the main quantity that limits their ability to transfer power is the inductive coupling factor \$k\$.
$$k=\frac{M}{\sqrt{L_1L_2}}$$
Where \$M\$ is the mutual inductance. The value of \$k\$ lies between 0 and 1, and the closer to 1, the tighter the coupling, and the more effective will be power transfer.

"The inductance of the transmit coil should correspond to the needs of the transmitter, and the inductance of the receive coil should correspond to the needs of the receiver." May I know from where I will get these needs.

@Confused That is a difficult question to answer in the abstract, i.e. without a specific circuit. Each circuit is different and poses different challenges. One general idea, though, is to try to match the impedance of the transmit coil to the output impedance of the transmitter to maximize the power delivered to the transmit coil.

First of all, OP has measured inductance not impedance. He will probably want to measure and record both the inductance and series resistance for design purposes.
Most people will use an integrated circuit for driving the transmitter and receiver coils. If so, consult the datasheet for information on design.
If not, OP should simulate the entire system he has designed and then optimize. I would expect that reasonable efficiency would be possible with the coils he has provided the series resistances are not too large. Have fun.
By the way, careful attention to the magnetic circuit is important. That is: use of backing ferrite sheets, coil alignment, roughly comparable size.
